Why does the direction of gravity not change in an accelerating elevator?
When an accelerating elevator goes up we take pseudo-force as down and when the elevator goes down we take the pseudo-force as up. This changes the effective gravity but why doesn’t the direction of gravity become different (opposite)? It is also in a different frame so what is going on exactly?

Why should effective gravity be upward? Are you falling to the roof of the elevator?

No haha like when elevator goes up we take pseudo force down and when down we take pseudo force up so imagine I am the non inertial frame so then add to that when I am going down the world is going up

The pseudo-force that we introduce if working in the non-inertial frame of the accelerating elevator depends only on the magnitude and direction of the elevator's acceleration. It has nothing to do with gravity - which become clear if you consider a situation where there is no gravity.

Gravity(a real force) always points downward, no matter what frame you're in because it is due to the attraction from Earth's gravitational field. When the elevator accelerates, a pseudo-force acts opposite to the elevator's motion. This changes the effective gravity, but gravity itself doesn’t change direction—it’s just the pseudo-force that alters the overall effect.

Okay thanksssss

If a monkey was to move up a rope then the acceleration of the monkey from the frame of the monkey’s eyes is downwards and the gravity is down too?  And tension is up?

The monkey sees and feels gravity (mg) pulling it downward.
The monkey also feels the tension (T) from the rope pulling it upward.
Although the monkey is accelerating upward in reality,but from its own perspective (inside its body or its "frame of reference"), it experiences the effort of climbing, which might make it "feel" like the acceleration is downward. This is simply the monkey perceiving the difficulty of working against gravity, not the actual direction of acceleration.
If the tension force exceeds gravity (T > mg), the monkey will accelerate upward relative to the ground.

Ooooohhhh okayyy thank you sm for the clearing upppp
